# How to mathematically note down "sum of all elements / numbers of elements"

Tags: notation

I have 1-n elements and I sum them up (I1+I2+I3...In)/N. Also for 5,5,8 the result is 6. I am not sure about the mathematical notation of the formula.

Comment: How about $\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}a_i}{N}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want notation for the average (the [arithmetic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean), to be precise)?

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^N I_k$$